# Circular dependency found: Http Response Interceptor 401

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

The basic idea was to use an Http Response Interceptor to redirect my webpage if it gives an 401 status. But i don't know if i am doing this the right way: i thought it was something like this but i seems more difficult than it seems. At the moment i get an Circular dependency found.

Do i need to push the interceptor somewhere else? And how can the interceptor know if i get an 401 request. is it also possible to define which 401 needs to be intercept and which ones ignored

```
   (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('app', ['ngRoute','ngCookies','ngMessages'])
            .config(routeConfig);

        routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider','$httpProvider'];


        function routeConfig($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
            $routeProvider

                .when('/', {

                    templateUrl: 'login.html',
                    controller : 'LoginController'
                })
                .when('/register', {

                    templateUrl: 'register.html',
                    controller : 'RegisterController'
                })
                .when('/main', {
                  //This gives an 401 status when the user has not been logged in
                    templateUrl: 'home.html',
                    controller : 'HomeController'

                })

                .otherwise('/');


            // We need to add this for csrf protection
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

            //this gives an Circular dependency error
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpResponseInterceptor');

        }

    })();
```

This is my service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('HttpResponseInterceptor', HttpResponseInterceptor);

    HttpResponseInterceptor.$inject = ['$rootScope','$http','$q','$location'];
    function HttpResponseInterceptor($rootScope,$http,$q,$location) {

        return {
            response: function(response){
                if (response.status === 401) {

                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401) {

                    $location.path('/login');
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };

    }

})();
```

**Update2**

As mention in the comment i was injecting to much stuff. So this is one problem fixed, but now when i go to the login page it makes a request on loading the page  (localhost:8080/user) which results in an infinite loop of redirection to the login page and with a browser crash as result.

So is there a way i can say to the Interceptor which url's needed to be redirected and which ones don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answer to 2nd problem ...

You query the rejection object and add some further conditions to your IF statement ...

you can dump rejection object with ...

console.log(JSON.stringify(rejection));

then add conditions to your IF ...

```
if (rejection.status === 401 && rejection.config.url !== "/url/you/do/not/want/to/change/state/on") {

    // do state.go or something else here

 }
```

Comment: You will prob want to use the JS indexOf method to check if the URL does (returns 0 or more) or does not (returns -1) contain a certain string, for example "/Jesus/loves/you".indexOf ("loves") === 7 ... "/Jesus/loves/you".indexOf ("hello") === -1

Comment: This is really awesome of you danday for helping me out. Now i understand angular just a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

does injecting services using $injector help?

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('admin')
    .factory('HttpInterceptor', httpInterceptor);

  httpInterceptor.$inject = [
    '$q',         // return promises
    '$injector'   // login service injection
  ];

  function httpInterceptor(q, injector) {
return {
  responseError: function (rejection) {

    var url = rejection.config ? rejection.config.url : undefined;
    var state = injector.get("$state");

    if (rejection.status === 401) {
      if (!(url === "/api/logout" || state.current.name === "login" && url === "/api/authenticated")) {
        var loginService = injector.get('LoginService');
        loginService.logout();
      }
    }

    if (rejection.status === 403) {
      state.go("home");
    }
    return q.reject(rejection);
  }
};
  }
}());
```

Comment: Your injecting a lot of stuff you arent using ... HttpResponseInterceptor.$inject = ['$rootScope','$http','$q','$location']; but you only use q and location - does removing the other stuff help?

Comment: Now the application works but when i go to /main it show a black page instead of been redirect to the login page

Comment: OK im guessing this line is getting fired ... $location.path('/login'); ... which looks wrong to me ... you instead need $stage.go('/'); (and will need to inject state service) ... In my code I had to inject state with $injector, not sure why, you may not need this ... but $state.go works for ui-router (which I think you are using but might be wrong)

Comment: You where right it was because of bad configuration of the inject. But now i get a second problem. I updated my answer if your interesting in helping me a bit further :)